# Book with creatures surrounding a family in a house but they're not always visible

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for a book which focuses on a child and his family. I think there was a big house and there were creatures around the house but the creatures weren't visible all the time. There was something that made them visible but I don't remember what it was. The child's family didn't believe him at first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I didn't read the book but there was a movie I watched that was based on a [book series of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spiderwick_Chronicles). It is called [*The Spiderwick Chronicles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spiderwick_Chronicles_(film)) (2008). A family movies in to a new house and there are creatures living around it. There's a book that's telling information about them. And the creatures are visible through a stone.

This is the stone from the movie. I don't know if it is the same in the books.

[image: The young boy with black hair raises the stone ring to his eye]